# SQLalchemy filter query only returning first row

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue with an SQLalchemy query. When i query a specific table it returns 7 items but when I iterate over it, it only finds one item.

Here is the query;

```
seasons = db.session.query(Seasons).filter(Seasons.tmdb_id == tmdb_id)
```

I know it returns 7 items because I immediately type the following and it prints the numeber "7";

```
print(seasons.count())
```

However when I try to iterate over this seasons object like this expecting to get 7 names, I only get one row with one name.

```
for item in seasons:
    print(item.name)
```

Here is my Seasons class in my models.py

```
# Main TV show table
class Seasons(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tv_seasons'
    tmdb_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    season_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    air_date = db.Column(db.String)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    episode_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    overview = db.Column(db.String)
    poster_path = db.Column(db.String)
    season_number = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What type of table data you query? can you provide us with more info about the result.
add example of your results.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `count()` function returns a int value.
Take a look: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.count

```sql
SELECT count(1) AS count_1 FROM (
    SELECT <rest of query follows...>
) AS anon_1
```

> The above SQL returns a single row, which is the aggregate value of the count function; the Query.count() method then returns that single integer value.

So, you should to use `Query(...).all()` to iterate on items.

then use `if` to check if has data:

```py
seasons = query(...).all()

if seasons: 
    for item in seasons:
        print(item.name)
```